# transition effect animations in VelocityJS

Tags: javascript, css, transition, velocity.js

I am using the velocity-animate module. I have a division to which I wanna apply some effects like `transition.flipXOut` or `transition.flipBounceXIn`. ( Any effect which is in the "Effect: Pre-Registered" section of this [Link](http://velocityjs.org/#uiPack) ).

Till now I have tried the following code for transitions.

```
Velocity(element, "flipXOut", {duration: 1500, easing: "easeInOutCirc"}) //Not working

Velocity(element, "transition.flipXOut", {duration: 1500, easing: "easeInOutCirc"}) // not working
```

How can I use all these transitions with the velocity-animate module?

PS: I am not using jQuery and will not be using the velocity cdn as well.

Comment: Velocity.js somewhat depends on jQuery library internally. You need to include compatible jQuery library in HTML first and then include Velocity library.

I think you misinterpreted what the Velocity's documentation is telling. When they say "without jQuery" that doesn't mean you won't need jQuery library itself, it all means you will not need to include jQuery functions within your code. Those jQuery function will be replaced by equivalent Velocity functions.

Comment: I know that. I am saying that I am not using jQuery to get element id's. I am using javascript DOM. All my other velocity animations are working except for the effects ones.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add `velocity.ui.js` file in your header.

See this for more info https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/06/faster-ui-animations-with-velocity-js/